# RichTextBox Paragraph content displays in middle of page

Tags: windows-phone-7, richtextbox, paragraph

I started programming for windows a few days ago and having trouble displaying my RichTextBox Paragraph element content at the top left corner. It displays in the middle of the content page for my grid.

Here is my code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <RichTextBox>
            <Paragraph TextAlignment="Left">
                <Bold FontSize="32">Todays Instructions</Bold>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
                I want some text to display here.
            </Paragraph>
        </RichTextBox>
    </Grid>
```

If you look at the content box of this message you see where I said "Hi Everyone" starts at the top left most corner. I want my paragraph to do the same but instead it displays in the middle of the grid. Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `VerticalAlignment="Top"` to your RichTextBox.

Comment: No that just centers the paragraph. I want it to display at the top left. I can't post an image because I don't have 10 reputation points so I'll give you a visual idea. Say if you open up Microsoft word and start typing. Everything displays at the top left. That's how I want my richtextbox to appear in the grid but instead it displays in the middle of the page like if you were to open up microsoft word and press the enter key a few times and then start typing. That's how my richtextbox is currently displayed.

Comment: Updated answer. You're paragraph is left aligned just add VerticalAlignment